# How to create oval gradient in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I need oval gradient for a background, but all I'm able to get is perfectly round gradient with `Brush.radialGradient(..)`:

```kotlin
Modifier
    .fillMaxSize()
    .background(
        brush = Brush.radialGradient(
            colors = listOf(Color(0xFFffffff), Color(0xFF000000)),
        ),
    )
```

This is what I need (the shape of the oval must of course be aligned with screen size ratio):

[image: This is what I need]

But all I am able to produce, is this:

[image: This is what I am able to produce]

Any ideas on how can I solve this?

Comment: Please post your code and if you can post clearer screens. I am able to see just 2 black boxes.

Comment: Hey @GabrieleMariotti, I created images with more contrast. This should be OK now. About the code: I posted it, but it's really nothing much. Doesn't seem to be any property to set the height and width or anything like it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Radical gradient shouldn't stretch like this, it determine pixel color depending on  distance from the center.

I'm not sure why there's no "Oval" gradient, but it's missing from android itself, and compose is just an interlayer here.

What is usually done in the android is just scaling the view. You can do it on compose too:

```
BoxWithConstraints(
    Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
) {
    val aspectRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight
    Box(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .scale(maxOf(aspectRatio, 1f), maxOf(1 / aspectRatio, 1f))
            .background(
                brush = Brush.radialGradient(
                    colors = listOf(Color(0xFFffffff), Color(0xFF000000)),
                ),
            )
    )
}
```

Here I'm using `BoxWithConstraints` to get `maxWidth` and `maxHeight`, in order to calculate needed scale.

[image]